# I need a custom wc-template-functions.php file

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to change the layout of my single product page. For this i need to change the file wc-template-functions.php (found in plugins/woocommerce/includes).

I know for changing the template files i have to copy the folder into my theme and rename it to "woocommerce" but how does it work for a file in the folder includes?

Comment: `wc-template-functions.php` is not a "tempate" and as such, it not one of the files you can copy over to your theme. Pretty much anything in that file is added to a hook in one of the templates and therefore cab be removed from those hooks and moved to other hooks. Please try to explain what you are hoping to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to change te layout of the single product page. as it is right now it starts with the product image. I want to move this to another position

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the template for the single product page, specifically [content-single.php](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/content-single-product.php#L39-41) you will see that the product images are attached to the `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary` hook.

To remove them you would need to use [`remove_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) and then to place them somewhere else you attach them to a different hook via [`add_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action):

```
function so_31406339_move_images(){
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images ', 20 );

  // for example, to move them to the very bottom of the page:
  add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images ', 30 );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'so_31406339_move_images' );
```